# Документация к проекту собранному с помощью Webpack

Tags: webpack

Доброго времени суток! Не так давно делал тестовое задание для конторы - приложение по прогнозу погоды. Собрал проект вебпаком, записал все используемые плагины в package.json. В итоге с конторы меня побрили, добился фидбека от тех. специалиста в котором был написал следующий кусок:

*Также кандидат использовал webpack, npm. Никакой документации по установке проекта не предоставил. В package.json записал зависимости только для dev версии, никаких скриптов не прописывал.*

Пытался гуглить какая же документация по установке проекта должна быть и какие скрипты нужно прописывать, ничего путнего не нашел. Собственно по-этому обращаюсь к вам уважаемые знатаки! О чем идет речь? Какую документацию нужно предоставлять и какие скрипты прописывать? Буду очень благодарен за ответ, так как в дальнейшем это поможет мне не допустить такой же ошибки!

файл package.json

```js
{
  "name": "application-name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.1",
    "less": "^2.7.2",
    "less-loader": "^4.0.3",
    "style-loader": "^0.16.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "webpack": "^2.3.3"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js выглядит так

```js
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');
const extractLESS = new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css');

module.exports = {

    entry: {
        index: './app/index.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './build'),
        publicPath: './build/',
        filename: '[name].js',
        library: '[name]'
    },

    watch: false,

    watchOptions: {
        aggregateTimeout: 100 
    },
    
    devtool: 'source-map',

    resolveLoader: {
        modules: ["node_modules"],
        moduleExtensions: ['-loader'],
        extensions: ["*", ".js"]
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
             test: /\.less$/i,
             use: extractLESS.extract(['css-loader', 'less-loader'])
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'url-loader'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    
    plugins: [
        extractLESS
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Все зависимости у вас для девелопмента - тоесть для того чтобы разрабатывать проект, а не для того чтобы просто собрать и использовать
пример:

```
"dependencies": {
   ...,
   'react@0.0.0'
}
```

Тоесть если я хочу не дописывать ничего в вашем проекте а просто собрать его для просмотра мне надо будет знать (точнее сборщику, а здесь это Вебпак) какие модуля/либы юзать

2) сама сборка - нету разделения для девелопмента и для собрки на продакшен. Надо прочитать доки, ничего сложного просто пару **переменных** в консоли передать, и эту команду сохранить в `package.json`. В конфиге проверить какой енвайермент (**переменная** что при запуске передана) и в соответсвии с этим делать разные манипуляции. К примеру `devtool` для продакшена лучше ставить `null`, так как зачем сорсмапы на проде - лишний вес.

3) вот после всего этого надо мини доку где написать какие команды (что прописаны в `package.json`) будут запускать сборку проекта, ДевСервер для разработки, проганять тесты  и тдтп

4) мой совет - просто гуглите любой проект с примером сборок качественных на ГитХабе, или же типа **react/angular/etc... webpack boilerplate/bootstrap** и смотрите как люди пишут